# Jboss EAP 7.4 class loading isolation

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

We are deploying 3 war files in Jboss EAP 7.4. All 3 war files have a dependency on a  module which contains spring, hibernate and lots of other jar files. Is there a way to have complete isolation between  classloading of the war files as we think module classes are shared between wars and causing issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modules are loaded in their own class loader which will be shared across all its dependents. If you need Spring to be in a unique class loader for each WAR your best options is to include Spring in each WAR.

Comment: Thanks, there are no other way ? We are little late and can't bundle the jars within war.

Comment: No, it's the only way. Those class loaders are meant to be shared for lower memory overhead as well as other reasons. I'm not sure how it's too late to just include the libraries in your WAR though.

Comment: We have 50+ wars.

Comment: I'm not a Spring expert, but I don't think it's meant to be shared across multiple deployments. I'm not really sure what could be done here.